# How to mark SWL contacts on eQSL?

Tags: logging

I fairly frequently get SWL reports via eQSL. I'm never quite sure what I should do with them. I know that eQSL has SWL capabilities, but I can never tell if I'm actually stating that a contact was one way, or two ways. What should I do? Here's the text, with the call changed (#= number, *= letter).

```
IZ####SWL   26Mar2014
Cfm ur QSO with IK#*** R-19 PSE QSL Vy 73 de Claudio
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The To line in the details will include a phrase something like "Confirming SWL reception of JT65 QSO". If you see something like that, then you know you can correctly mark it, assuming that the contact info is in your log, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You just confirm them like you do regular contacts (check them and move to archive). The text on regular contacts states, "This confirms our **2-way** SSB QSO", so since the text on SWL contacts, it's all good.

Comment: So confirm it if it doesn't say 2 way, reject it if it says 2 way?

Answer (score 0):

Myself, i erase the 599 report since it is a one way contact make a comment and confirm it in. Nothing wrong with a one way, i still listen in a lot while doing other things. It is interesting to have SWL reports because i was a SWL when i was a kid in the 50's and receiving distant stations was very interesting, BBC, VOA, Radio South Africa RSA, HCJB of course and the biggest Bommer on the band, Rado Moscow. I am glad for the interest in SWL.   73.  KDØQG